# how can a download a real time dataset as a csv file and work on it

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I am currently working on datascience intern,as my instructure told me to chart the real time datasets. unfortunatly i am not able to find any dataset in internet to download. could any one help me to find a csv of real time dataset